# How could this solution to an easy probability problem be considered wrong?

Tags: probability

I was asked to re-check an exam my brother just got back. His solution to the following problem was marked as false by his teacher:

> A user sits in front of a computer with a keyboard with 26 keys for the lower-case letters (a, b, c, ...z) and randomly hits the keys. What is the probability he types the word "passwort"?

The solution my brother gave:

> The word "passwort" has 8 letters. Therefore the probability to type it is $\frac{1}{26}^8 = 4.788E-12$

Which is also the solution I would have come up with. So is this solution wrong, and why is it wrong?

Comment: That assumes the user will type exactly 8 characters and then stops.  He might type two at random, seven, or 35.  So you must multiply $\frac 1{26}^8$ by the probability that the user will type exactly eight characters.  Which we do not have enough information to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the answer I would give, except I would stop at $\frac 1{26^8}$.  Maybe your teacher wants to consider he might press a different number of keys than $8$.  Maybe your teacher objects to the equal sign when they are not equal (though they are close).  Ask your teacher why it is wrong.

Comment: Or the teacher isn't very smart...  Which happens a lot.